# Any chance to save merging data Google and Facebook contacts?

Tags: contacts, facebook, google-contacts

after factory reset of my Motorola Atrix (2.3.7 Android) I can easily restore SMS messages, E-mail, call-history and etc. My problem is that after the reste I have to merge manually contacts imported from Google accounts and the Facebook.

How can I save the mentioned information?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a HTC phone, with Facebook for HTC Sense, there is an option to backup your merged contacts. It actually use the comment field to put a `<HTCData>` tag.

*(I don't remember exactly the option, so feel free to edit)*

Some facebook sync applications such as [HaxSync](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dorg.mots.haxsync&ei=E7f7UaTPH8ahkAWn8YGQBA&usg=AFQjCNEyxFvJp0b9D2IkKm4O1JWfXFQl9g&sig2=dkI2KfZOAejHnl-SpkIrHg&bvm=bv.50165853,d.dGI) (paid) provide an option to backup contacts links informations. (In the case of HaxSync, it uses HTC tags, so it is compatible with Facebook for HTC Sense and others applications that may also use HTC tags).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try one of the many apps written to do just this like [Merge+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android.merger&hl=en).

If that's not what you're looking for, there's also the possibility of exporting all your contacts to Google and merging them by doing this:

1. Open Google Mail
2. Click *Gmail* under the Google logo and select *Contacts*
3. Click on the *More* button above the contact list and select *Find & merge duplicates...*

Comment: "Find & merge duplicates" in Google Mail, won't have any effect on non-GMail contacts, like Facebook ones.